# Applying torque to rigid body on a fixed axel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose I have a torque $\tau \in \mathbb{R}^3$ on a rigid body, about its center of gravity, where the direction of $\tau$ is the axis of the torque and the magnitude of $\tau$ is the strength of the torque.

Let's suppose the rigid body is on some infinitely strong fixed axel, through its center of gravity, with unit vector axis $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^3, |\alpha| = 1$.  Notice that $\tau$ and $\alpha$ may be in different directions.

The torque $\tau$ is therefore equivalent to some torque $k\alpha$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\tau$ and $\alpha$ are perpendicular ($\tau \cdot \alpha = 0$) then $k$ is zero because the torque would be entirely absorbed by the axel.

If $\tau$ and $\alpha$ are collinear, then there exists some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c\alpha = \tau$.  In such a case none of the torque is absorbed by the axel, and $k = c$

For the remaining cases what is $k$ in terms of $\tau$ and $\alpha$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Saying that the torque $\vec\tau$ and the rotation axis $\vec\alpha$ forms an angle $\theta$ in between. The projection of $\vec\tau$ on $\vec\alpha$ is

$$
\tau_\parallel=\tau \cos\theta
$$

Hence, the angular acceleration is

$$
c \alpha = \tau_\parallel = \tau \cos \theta\\
k \alpha = \frac{c}{\cos\theta}\alpha=\tau\\
k = \frac{c}{\cos\theta}
$$

Comment: ...or just use the dot product and don't worry about angles.